# Cross-product identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, cross-product

This [page of vector identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra_relations#Addition_and_multiplication_of_vectors) lists the following (among many other identities):
$$
(\mathbf{A}\cdot(\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{C}))\,\mathbf{D}= (\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{D} )\left(\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{C}\right)+\left(\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{D}\right)\left(\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{A}\right)+\left(\mathbf{C}\cdot\mathbf{D}\right)\left(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}\right)
$$
which is presumably supposed to hold for vectors $\mathbf{A,B,C,D} \in \Bbb R^3$. Unlike the other identities, this one is given without justification or citation.  With this in mind, my questions are:

1. <s>Is the identity true?</s> *(proven in answers below)*
2. Is the identity well-known? Is there a citation that can be used here?
3. How can we prove it?

Some answers have been given, but alternate approaches would be interesting to see.

Thank you for your consideration.

---

Quick thoughts on the problem:

- $\mathbf{A}\cdot(\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{C})$ is a scalar-triple product and can be rewritten as
  $$ 
  \det \pmatrix{\mathbf{A}& \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{C}}
  $$
- I have a hunch Cauchy-Binet can be applied here somehow
- This amounts to a statement about the map
  $$
  D \mapsto [(A \times B)(C\cdot D) + (B \times C)(A\cdot D) + (C \times A)(B\cdot D)]
  $$
- A proof in [Levi-Cevita notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) might be quick.

Comment: It is true. Just apply formula number 8 in two different ways to the expression $A\times ((B\times C)\times D)=-A\times(D\times(B\times C))$.

Comment: @Pythagoras That's a neat idea!  You should consider writing that out into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By formula number 8 in the above link, we may derive from $$A\times((B\times C)\times D)=-A\times (D\times(B\times C))$$ $$\Leftrightarrow (A\cdot D)(B\times C)-(A\cdot(B\times C))D=-A\times((D\cdot C)B-(D\cdot B)C),$$ from which the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

A (reasonably) quick proof of the statement: let $M$ be the matrix whose columns are $A,B,C$. I claim that the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $M^T$ (i.e. the cofactor matrix of $M$) is given by
$$
\operatorname{adj}(M^T) = \pmatrix{B \times C & C \times A & A \times B}.
$$
This is simple enough to verify with computation.  From there, it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
(B \times C)A^T + (C \times A)B^T + (A \times B)C^T &= \pmatrix{B \times C & C \times A & A \times B}M^T 
\\ & = \operatorname{adj}(M^T)M^T = \det(M)I = \det \pmatrix{A & B & C} I.
\end{align}
$$
Now, take the equation 
$$
\det \pmatrix{A & B & C} I = (B \times C)A^T + (C \times A)B^T + (A \times B)C^T
$$
and multiply (from the right) by the vector $D$.  The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 2):

Since the two sides of the equation are linear in each factor, we may reduce $A, B, C$ to basis vectors. Further, if two of $A, B, C$ are equal, then both sides are $0$. Thus we may assume $A=e_i,\,B=e_j,\,C=e_k$ with $i,j,k$ mutually distinct.

In this case $B\times C$ is a scalar multiple of $A$, so $B\times C=((B\times C)\cdot A)A$.

Denote the matrix $(B \times C)A^T + (C \times A)B^T + (A \times B)C^T$ as $E$. Then the $i$-th column of $E$ is (matrix multiplies on a column):
$$E\cdot A=B\times C=((B\times C)\cdot A)A=\det \pmatrix{\mathbf{A}& \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{C}}A.$$
Here note that $e_i^T e_j=\begin{cases}1,&i=j\\0,&i\ne j\end{cases}$.

Similarly, we can show that the $j$-th and the $k$-the columns of $E$ are the same as those of $\det \pmatrix{\mathbf{A}& \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{C}}I$.

Therefore $$E=\det \pmatrix{\mathbf{A}& \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{C}}I,$$
which is what we want to prove.

**Remark:**

In essence this is a proof using Levi-Civita notation, since $e_i\times e_j=\epsilon_{ijk}e_k$.

**Edit:**

I shall show the reduction step here for the rigor.

Write $A=\sum a_ie_i$, $B=\sum b_ie_i$, and $C=\sum c_ie_i$.

Then 
\begin{align*}
  (B \times C)A^T + (C \times A)B^T + (A \times B)C^T
  &=(\sum b_ie_i\times{\sum c_ie_i}) (\sum a_ie_i)^T + \cdots\\
  &=\sum_{i,j,k}(b_ic_ja_k)\left((e_i\times e_j)e_k^T+(e_j\times e_k)e_i^T+(e_k\times e_i)e_j^T\right).
\end{align*}

And clearly $\det\pmatrix{A&B&C}=\sum_{i,j,k}b_ic_ja_k\det\pmatrix{e_k&e_i&e_j}$.

So if we can prove the equation ofr basis vectors, then the equation holds.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Since the two sides of the equation are linear in each factor, we may reduce $A, B, C$ to basis vectors:" this is interesting if it could be made to work, but dubious without further justification.  For instance: if we wanted to prove the "triple vector product" identity
$$
A \times (B \times C) = (A \cdot C)B - (A \cdot B)C,
$$
then proving this in the case where $A,B,C$ are the standard basis vectors is clearly insufficient. Both sides are linear in each vector, though.

Comment: Also, we could incorrectly apply your logic to conclude that $A \times (B \times C) = 0$ for all linearly independent $A,B,C$

Comment: But the logic does not imply that $A \times (B \times C) = 0$ for all linearly independent $A,B,C$: it only implies that it is $0$ for orthogonal $A, B, C$, which is correct. The point is that the sides of the equation $A\times(B\times C)=(A\cdot C)B-(A\cdot B)C$ are not $0$ when two of them are equal: when $A=B$, there is no reason for $A\times(B\times C)$ to be $0$.

Comment: But your statement "since the two sides of the equation are linear in each factor, we may reduce $A, B, C$ to basis vectors" makes no reference to how each side of the equation behaves for linearly dependent $A,B,C$, which means that it can't generally be correct.

Comment: The first step is to reduce it to basis vectors, not necessarily linearly independent. Then we use the property that, if two of the factors are equal, then both sides of the equation are $0$, to reduce to different basis vectors.

Comment: The reduction step is nice! Certainly checks out now

Comment: And that's an interesting point.  I suspect that there's an "obvious" statement to be made here about multilinear functions

Comment: I think the statement I'm looking for is this: for a multilinear map on $V_1\times \cdots \times V_n$, it suffices to plug in all basis vectors, even those that are not linearly independent.  We can think of this as extracting the columns of the matrix of the corresponding linear map on $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n$

Comment: Sorry for the comment-spam.  Anyway, fantastic answer and thank you

Comment: No problem. Your statement is what I meant in the first sentence. Thanks for pointing out the need for an explicit proof.