# Triple product property

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I want to show how can be expressed the following difference involving triple products: given four vectors $\mathbf {a}, \mathbf b, \mathbf c, \mathbf d \in \mathbb R^3$
\begin{equation}
[(\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) \cdot \mathbf c] \, \mathbf d - (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf c) (\mathbf b \times \mathbf d)
\end{equation}

This because in my application the second expression involving the term $\mathbf b \times \mathbf d$ has physical meaning. I have played with the properties of the triples product without getting results. I cannot find an expression that connects the two quantities.

Comment: This is a vector with $i$th component$$\epsilon_{mjk}a_jb_kc_md_i-\epsilon_{ijk}a_lc_lb_jd_k=\epsilon_{mjk}(a_jb_kc_md_i-\delta_{im}a_lb_jc_ld_k).$$It's not obvious this can be simplified. Note your original expression has a term parallel to $d$ followed by another orthogonal to it; the projections onto $d$ and a plane orthogonal to it give each term an easy meaning, but there's no obvious reason we should be able to do something more insightful than that.

Comment: You could [expand the first term](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3496791/81360), which would give you a sum of terms that each have the form $(w \cdot x)(y \times z)$.