# Show that $V (u ×v, v ×w, w ×u) = (V (u, v, w))^2$, where $V$ is the triple product.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $V (u ×v, v ×w, w ×u) = (V (u, v, w))^2$. The identity $(u ×v) ×w = (u|w)v −(v|w)u$ might be useful. I have no idea how to solve this.

**Edit:** $V$ denotes the triple product so $V(u,v,w)=(u\times v)|w$

**Edit2:** If $s=v\times w$ then $V (u ×v,s, w ×u)=((u×v)×s)|v$.

Thus $(u×v)×s)=(u|s)v −(v|s)u=(u|(v\times w))v −(v|(v\times w))u=(u|(v\times w))v$.

It follows that $V (u ×v,v\times w, w ×u)=(u|(v\times w)v)|(w\times u)=(v|(w\times u))v|(w\times u)=vV(v,w,u)|(w\times u)=V(vV(v,w,u),w,u)=V(vV(u,v,w),w,u)=V(u,vV(u,v,w),w)=V(u,v,w)V(u,v,w)$.

So I used the linear property of $V$ to take out the scalar $V(u,v,w)$ and "parity" property that says if I interchange the variables of $V$ an even number then the value is the same.

Comment: What is a formula for $V(x,y,z)$?

Comment: So what does your formula give for the cross-product of two cross-products?

Comment: This problem seems to be completely mechanical where you just put the things into the formula and then get to the answer after some manipulations. It's not very clear why you have no idea how to solve the problem, unless you have never done any problems with the cross product before.

Comment: I have never done something like this. If I can get an answer though I can study it and see where it went wrong for me.

Comment: You have to learn to figure things out when you haven’t necessarily been shown a similar problem. Answer my second comment. (By formula I meant the identity.)

Comment: There are different ways to learn and I don't agree with you but I respect it.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure what you want me to do but using the identity and cyclic property I got that the following $V(u×v,v×w,w×u)=(v\cdot(w\times u))v\cdot(w\times u)$

Comment: You seem to have mistaken $V(u,v,w)$ as the vector triple product $(u\times v)\times w$. Since the RHS is a square, $V$ cannot possibly be vector-valued. It has to be scalar-valued. Here $V(u,v,w)$ should mean the scalar triple product $(u\times v)\cdot w$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I solved it incorrectly (lol) check the edit.

Comment: @user1551 no no, I'm just bad at calculating.

Comment: @perpersson : At the beginning of your edit2, "V (u ×v,s, w ×u)=((u×v)×s)|w xu", is not it ?

Comment: That's right I think $V(u\times v,s,w\times u)=((u\times v)\times s)\cdot (w\times u)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s=v\times w$ then

$V(u\times v,s,w\times u)=\langle(u\times v)\times s,w\times u\rangle$

Thus

$(u\times v)\times s=\langle u,s\rangle v-\langle v,s \rangle u=\langle u,v\times w\rangle v-\langle v,v\times w \rangle u=\langle v \times w,u\rangle v=V(v,w,u)v=V(u,v,w)v$

It follows that

$V(u \times v,v \times w, w \times u)=V(u,v,w)\langle v,w \times u\rangle=V(u,v,w)\langle w \times u,v\rangle=V(u,v,w)^2$

Q.E.D. (just mechanical)

Comment: I have a doubt that $det(v,w,u)=det(u,v,w)$ but others will want to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why a doubt? That's a cyclic permutation, which is an even permutation.

Comment: @TedShifrin : yes. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\pmatrix{u\times v&v\times w&w\times u}=\operatorname{adj}\pmatrix{w&u&v}^T$ (see also Ben Grossman's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3496804)). Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
V(u\times v,\,v\times w,\,w\times u)
&=\det\pmatrix{u\times v&v\times w&w\times u}\\
&=\det\operatorname{adj}\pmatrix{w&u&v}^T\\
&=\left(\det\pmatrix{w&u&v}\right)^2\\
&=\left(\det\pmatrix{u&v&w}\right)^2\\
&=V(u,v,w)^2.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I just wonder how you justify the third equality? Is that another known fact, or are you using Cramer's rule:
$$adj(w\ u\ v)^T (w\ u\ v)=det (w\ u\ v) I_3,$$
giving us
$$\det(adj(w\ u\ v)^T) \det (w\ u\ v) =(\det(w\ u\ v))^3,$$and cancelling one factor?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, that's the usual proof. Admittedly this isn't taught in introductory courses on linear algebra, but I think it gives a better proof to the OP's identity than invoking the [vector quadruple product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_product#Vector_quadruple_product), which in my humble opinion is more mysterious.